# Can ActiveRecord connect to PostgreSQL remotely and protect the DB password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a PostgreSQL DB on a remote VPS server (CentOS 5) and I'd like to connect to have a Rails application connect to it from my local Mac laptop. On my laptop, I have the ActiveRecord PostgreSQL adapter installed -- `postgres (0.7.9.2008.01.28)`.

I read in the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/auth-methods.html):

> The password-based authentication methods are md5, crypt, and password. These methods operate similarly except for the way that the password is sent across the connection: respectively, MD5-hashed, crypt-encrypted, and clear-text.

[...]

> If you are at all concerned about password "sniffing" attacks then md5 is preferred...Plain password should be avoided especially for connections over the open Internet (unless you use SSL, SSH, or another communications security wrapper around the connection).

In a standard Rails `database.yml` would have something like this for a localhost connection...

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: journalapp_development
  username: xxx
  password: yyy
  host: localhost
```

But there's nothing in there about the authentication method discussed in the PostgreSQL docs. Is there as option to have something like "`auth_method: md5`"?

Comment: To clarify, are you having connection issues?

Comment: No, just investigating how I might connect securely across the general Internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of whether Postgres allows this functionality, you can enable a secure connection to a remote database by using SSH tunneling.  Here's the gratuitous Stack Overflow paste-in from the Web docs:

> First make sure that an SSH server is
>   running properly on the same machine
>   as the PostgreSQL server and that you
>   can log in using ssh as some user.
>   Then you can establish a secure tunnel
>   with a command like this from the
>   client machine:
>
> ssh -L 3333:foo.com:5432 joe@foo.com
>   The first number in the -L argument,
>   3333, is the port number of your end
>   of the tunnel; it can be chosen
>   freely. The second number, 5432, is
>   the remote end of the tunnel: the port
>   number your server is using. The name
>   or IP address between the port numbers
>   is the host with the database server
>   you are going to connect to. In order
>   to connect to the database server
>   using this tunnel, you connect to port
>   3333 on the local machine:
>
> psql -h localhost -p 3333 postgres To
>   the database server it will then look
>   as though you are really user
>   joe@foo.com and it will use whatever
>   authentication procedure was
>   configured for connections from this
>   user and host. Note that the server
>   will not think the connection is
>   SSL-encrypted, since in fact it is not
>   encrypted between the SSH server and
>   the PostgreSQL server. This should not
>   pose any extra security risk as long
>   as they are on the same machine.

In case you want more, you can find it online by searching for "SSL tunnel" or "postgres SSL tunnel".  Here's the Postgres site where I got the above:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssh-tunnels.html

To summarize for Rails, you would then do the following:

1) In a terminal window, run the first ssh command above to establish the tunnel.

2) Set your database props like so:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: journalapp_development
  username: xxx
  password: yyy
  host: localhost
  port: 3333
```

Comment: I believe you meant to write "SSH tunneling" in your first sentence.

Comment: This only works if the sshd on the server accepts connections on its foo.com interface. It is easier to substitute the first foo.com for localhost.

Comment: @runako Would you need to have PostgreSQL installed on both systems for this to work though? Otherwise, how would you run `psql ...` on the client machine?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look online and there doesn't seem to be an option for what you're looking for and in fact the client library, [libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq.html) doesn't mention this either.

My guess is that this is negotiated on your behalf within libpq. In any case, md5 is likely to be the default authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to a PostgreSQL server over insecure channel you **need** to encrypt your communication with [SSL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html) or (as runako has explained) [SSH Tunneling](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssh-tunnels.html).