# Is using Heroku Postgres secure against MITM attacks?

Tags: postgresql, security, ssl, heroku, heroku-postgres

With questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361652/tcp-connections-to-postgres-secure-ssl-required), it looks like the only way to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks is to use `sslmode=verify-full`. This is also explained in the [Postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-ssl.html).

When I use the `DATABASE_URL` provided by Heroku in my app, is there a guarantee that there won't be a MITM attack? (Or asked another way, does Heroku do something behind the scenes to guarantee that `Heroku <-> Heroku-Postgres` is secure?)

Comment: MITM by whom? Heroku? NSA?

Comment: I would also be interested with everything you find related to PG Heroku security. Did you find an answer to this specific point? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

No, Heroku Postgres is not secure against a MitM. The highest risk is running `pg:psql` from the command line, since it's fairly easy to get between your laptop and Heroku by using a WiFi Pineapple or similar tools. Getting between your Dynos and the database is much harder. This is possible since Heroku hasn't created a CA to sign their database certificates, thus there's no trust root to use when you're connecting.

I did a writeup of actually performing such a MitM against Heroku Postgres [here](https://thusoy.com/2016/mitming-postgres), please file a support ticket with Heroku saying you'd like to see them create a CA and issue a trusted root we can use to authenticate connections if you care about this.

Comment: Has this changed at all in the past two years?

Comment: Nope, no changes. You can test your setup using this script: https://github.com/thusoy/postgres-mitm