# Postgres SSL connection failing to be established

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, heroku

I'm attempting to get a vagrant environment up to run a Rails application that connects to a remote Postgres database hosted on Heroku. Running the app from my host machine (Mac OS X) works just fine, but fails on a fresh Ubuntu installation in my vagrant box, even though they're pointed to the same source directory. Here's what I get when attempting to start the web server:

```
00:02:22 web.1  | Connecting to database specified by database.yml
00:02:22 web.1  | /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize': FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "207.172.212.123", user "user", database "database", SSL off (PG::ConnectionBad)
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `connect'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/composite_primary_keys-5.0.13/lib/composite_primary_keys/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification_changes.rb:47:in `retrieve_connection'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/composite_primary_keys-5.0.13/lib/composite_primary_keys/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification_changes.rb:29:in `connection'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /vagrant/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from config.ru:1:in `new'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
00:02:22 web.1  |   from /opt/ruby/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
00:02:22 web.1  | exited with code 1
```

I think the issue has to do with the pg gem not successfully establishing an SSL connection with Postgres. Is there something special that needs to be configured on the Ubuntu server to make the SSL connection happen?

Here is the database.yml:

```
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  database: database
  username: user
  password: password
  host: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  port: 5432
```

This config works from my Mac, but not the Ubuntu VM. I've also tried adding sslmode: require, which also didn't help.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html

Comment: @CraigRinger This documentation seems to focus more on the server side requirements as opposed to the client side. I'm connecting to a database hosted through Heroku and it works from my Mac using SSL, just not from Ubuntu. Any thoughts on why the client from the Ubuntu server will not connect using SSL?

Comment: Ah, ok. The usual issue is people not configuring SSL server-side. Not an issue if you're using Heroku (something you didn't mention anywhere, only "ubuntu server", which suggested you were self-hosting Pg).

Comment: @CraigRinger I updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: The problem is in the first line. This has nothing to do with Ruby or gems or Rails. Your Postgres server is rejecting the connection. I don't have an answer for you, but it has to do with Postgres permissions.

Comment: @ChrisJackson Please show your `database.yml` too, with usernames/passwords xxxx'd out.

Comment: @CraigRinger Updated with database.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key error portion is:

> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "207.172.212.123", user "user", database "database", SSL off

This tells you that you're not attempting to make an SSL connection. You'll want to explicitly tell `libpq` (which is what the Pg gem, and hence Rails, uses to connect to PostgreSQL) that you require an SSL connection, by finding a way to pass the `sslmode` parameter through to `libpq` with value `require`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2008773/398670) suggests that the Pg gem was modified to autonegotiate SSL. So at a guess, the version on your Mac is newer than the version on your Ubuntu box. For older versions it looks like there may not be a simple way to specify that SSL is required, but the JDBC URL format for the connection string with `ssl=true` may be used to work around the lack, per the first answer on that article, but that's a bit ugly.

Your comments suggest that your Pg gem doesn't understand `sslmode` as an option in `database.yml`, silently ignoring it.

In that case, I'd try using a connstring:

```
 adapter: postgresql
 database: "dbname=database host=207.172.212.123 user=user sslmode=require"
 ...
```

In general you can supply a connstring anywhere you can put a database name with `libpq`. You should leave out the `user`, `host`, etc keys in your `database.yml` if you do this. I haven't tested it with Rails, but this approach works with most things.

Or you could update your Pg gem to one that supports SSL properly. It looks like [the current version should support `sslmode`](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html) as a connection option.

**UPDATE**:

It turns out that SSL was not supported by the `libpq` on the Ubuntu box.

Comment: I'll try the changes to the database.yml, but both setups are using version 0.17.1 of the pg gem, as specified in the Gemfile.lock, which they both share.

Comment: @ChrisJackson That makes things more interesting. Different compile-time defaults in libpq? Does the libpq on your Ubuntu box support SSL? Try `psql "dbname=database host=207.172.212.123 user=user sslmode=require"` (with appropriate changes for real details).

Comment: Might be on to something here, I get this from the Ubuntu server: "psql: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in". However, the same command from my Mac successfully connects, so that's the differentiating factor.

Comment: Ok, got it working running these commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2 -y

Comment: @ChrisJackson So it was a build issue. In general I'd recommend using PostgreSQL packages from http://apt.postgresql.org/ rather than some random PPA, but glad you got it going.